# Clarification of Sakurai's argument for the WKB approximation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, approximations, semiclassical

In Sakurai's discussion of the WKB approximation in section 2.5.4 (3rd Ed.), he presents the following argument:

$$
\frac{d^2u_E(x)}{dx^2} + \frac{2m}{\hbar^2}\left[E-V(x)\right]u_E(x) = 0.
$$

Define $$k(x) := \left[\frac{2m}{\hbar^2}(E-V(x))\right]^{\frac{1}{2}}\qquad E > V(x) 
 \\ k(x) := -i\left[\frac{2m}{\hbar^2}(E-V(x))\right]^{\frac{1}{2}} \qquad E < V(x). $$

Then,
$$\frac{d^2u_E(x)}{dx^2} + [k(x)]^2u_E(x) = 0$$

try a solution of the form
$$u_E(x) = e^{\frac{iW(x)}{\hbar}}$$

then, the Schrödinger equation becomes

$$i\hbar \frac{d^2W}{dx^2} - \left(\frac{dW}{dx}\right)^2 + \hbar^2[k(x)]^2 = 0$$

Now, we consider the following restriction

$$\hbar \left\vert \frac{d^2W}{dx^2} \right\vert << \left\vert \frac{dW}{dx} \right\vert ^2 $$

Now, using the condition above we get a lowest order approximation for $W(x)$ $$W'_0(x) = \hbar k(x)$$

Leading to a first order approximation based on $$\left(\frac{dW}{dx}\right)^2 = \hbar^2[k(x)]^2 + i\hbar W_0''(x) = \hbar^2[k(x)]^2 + i\hbar^2k'(x) $$

My question is, did Sakurai get this by differentiation again
$$W'_0(x) = \hbar k(x)$$ and placing it into
$$\left(\frac{dW}{dx}\right)^2 = \hbar^2[k(x)]^2 + i\hbar^2k'(x), $$
or is there something else going on here?